# Github Pages return 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-pages

I have several github repos that I'm trying to publish as github pages. I've created gh-pages branches for them and their repo's say that the pages exist, but when I go to the links they provide I find a 404 page.

I know that github pages are finicky and return this error if the home page isn't called "index.html" and I suspect that the problem is related to that, but I'm not sure how to fix it. All of the projects in question are rails apps with homepages in the views/home called "index.html.erb" and routes designating those pages as root. Do I need to rename those pages or there some other way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github pages is used only for static websites, you cannot host applications on it.
You wrote that you hosted *.html.erb files, which means you are trying to setup a rails application on it.

You can use static website builders to create Github sites, or code them on your own.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@bukk530 is absolutely correct.

Additionally, it would be worth noting that GitHub Pages *does* support hosting Jekyll sites, but **nothing** else.  Static HTML/CSS/JavaScript and Jekyll.

Comment: that being said - accept @bukk530's answer, B.Allred  I'm merely adding an additional explanation.